# Save text file with different delimiters

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, text-files

I have a dataframe with 100 columns, how do I **export/save** it using df.to_csv() with sep = ',|;' ?

So after df.iloc[:, :15] with sep = ';' and df.iloc[:, 15:] with ','?

I have tried to look through documentations, but I cannot find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest using this vanilla python code to join two csv subfiles: `'\n'.join([a + ',' + b for a, b in zip(df.iloc[:, :15].to_csv(sep = ';').splitlines(), df.iloc[:, 15:].to_csv(sep = ',').splitlines())])`. Also maybe you need to put something between `a` and `b` as your separator of choice.

Comment: Also I found out that you may need to add params `header = False, index = False` to call of `.to_csv()` as you probably don't need row and column indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is no built in solution in `.to_csv()` for using two different separators in one call. Hence I suggest using next plain-Python solution, which just joins two (or any amoun of parts) csv parts rendered with different separators. `numpy` is just used for filling of dataframe with random numbers, and not necessary for csv creation.

In the code below I used for example limits `:15` and `15:` suggested by question author. Also I used `,` as a separator between line parts of two csv sub-files. Code can be extended to join any (not only two) number of csv sub-files rendered with different separators.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Example dataframe creation
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 40))

with open('result.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([','.join(line_parts) for line_parts in zip(*[
        df.iloc[:, begin : end].to_csv(sep = sep, header = False, index = False).splitlines()
        for begin, end, sep in [(None, 15, ';'), (15, None, ',')]
    ])]).encode('utf-8'))
```